# Is a disabled textbox any better than a div with role="textbox" for accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Consider that I have a form where one of the fields (name) is always disabled.

[image]

For accessibility, is using an `input`

```
 <label>
    Name 
    <input role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" value="Joe Shmoe" />
 </label>
```

any better than using `div`s

```
 <div>
   Name
   <div role="textbox" aria-readonly="true">Joe Shmoe</div>
 </div>
```

?

Comment: its the same i guess

Comment: If the field is always disabled, why is it a field?

Comment: @DA the idea is that for a logged-in user the field is disabled. For a guest user it is not disabled, but I can easily use an input in one case and a div in the other if needed. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Unless it's abundantly clear WHY a field is disabled, disabled fields should be avoided. They're just confusing to folks.

Comment: @GilBirman consistency is also important - so if they come to the page when logged-in, and when logged-out, they would expect it to be consistent. This is an example of the accessibility being a "usability lens" http://unobfuscated.blogspot.com/2015/02/what-is-accessibility.html do you really need to show them this information when logged-out? They are after all logged out and could be on a public computer.

Comment: @unobf thanks for the valuable input and link. Just one thing I think you mixed up -- in my case when the user is logged out they *will* have to enter a name. It's the logged **in** user who isn't allowed to enter a name (because a name is already permanently associated with her account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of label with input is better because the association between the text "Name" and the label is explicit and the user, using DOM navigation will be able to encounter and discover that explicit relationship which they would not in the case of the DIV.

Comment: I disagree. There are plenty of markup choices that will be less confusing than a label and a disabled input (a `dl` for example). As @DA notes in comments, a disabled input without a clearly stated reason is potentially confusing.

Comment: @steveax - the question is specifically about accessibility. You HAVE to have an explicit association between the label and the input field in order for it to be accessible. Label is the most widely supported accessible technique - therefore the acknowledged best practice. The DIV markup provided in the question IS NOT accessible - full stop. This is a fact, it is not debatable, it is not opinion. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-cues.html

Comment: Should form controls be associated with labels? Absolutely. Should a label and a div be paired? No. But what I'm suggesting is alternative markup (since the input will always be disabled) that avoids the potential confusion of the disabled input.

Comment: I probably could have been clearer and said: "I think neither of those markup choices are ideal".

Comment: duck (semantic) markup - if it looks like an input, and acts like an input (even a disabled one), then it should be an input. In the same vein, if the "input" is really acting like a heading, then it should look like a heading and be marked up as a heading.

Comment: Would the `<div>` markup be ok from an accessibility point of view if it had an `aria-label` attribute?